# Get 3 highest score in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
user_id  english   physics    geography   chemistry

  1        75        60          85          79
```

I want to show the users top 3 subject they got highest. So here we can see `user1` got highest in `geography`: `85` then in `chemistry` : `79` and then in `english` : `75`

So I will show later to the user that their top 3 scored subject are Geography, Chemistry and English and also show them the scores.

Please have a look at the table on fiddle:  [table link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa59/1)

Comment: Is this all being done in MySQL or are you using something like PHP, C#, or another programming language to actually retrieve the data? What you're asking to do is easy if the data is normalized but right now it isn't.

Comment: I would break them out into a table that holds all scores (user_id, subject, score) and select user_id, subject, score where user_id = ? order by score limit 3

Comment: Hi @HuskyHuskie I use PHP

Comment: See normalisation. (As exemplified below)

Answer (score 2):

Do you NEED to use this table structure? This would be MUCH easier if you had 2 tables.

`Users(user_id, name)` and `Grades(subject_name, score, user_id)`

You could then query:

```
SELECT Users.name, subject_name, score FROM Grades 
JOIN Users on Grades.user_id = Users.user_id
WHERE Users.user_id = ?
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
```

OR:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Users.name, subject_name, score FROM Grades 
JOIN Users on Grades.user_id = Users.user_id
WHERE Users.user_id = ?
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: @Darell If i break this into two tables and run your query will give me top 3 scores? ORDER BY score LIMIT 3: Does it actually produce the expected result? I will test it soon

Comment: You may want to modify `ORDER BY score` to be `ORDER BY score DESC` to ensure it's order is from largest to smallest.